# Trying to include boost serialization in project

Tags: c++, boost

I added -lboost_serialization in the makefile:

This is what I include in the main to use boost:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

when I compile I don't get errors but when I run the program I get this error message:

```
"./Project: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.63.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the makefile. Most likely problem is that your boost libraries are not on the path used by the linker. Do you know where they are installed?

Comment: Project: main.o Consolas.o Microsoft.o Sony.o Nintendo.o UsuarioAdmin.o UsuarioVendedor.o Juegos.o Venta.o EA.o Bugisoft.o Bandai.o JuegosSony.o JuegosNintendo.o JuegosMicrosoft.o Konami.o Sega.o SquareEnix.o ClaseAdmin.o
 g++ main.o Consolas.o Microsoft.o Sony.o Nintendo.o UsuarioAdmin.o UsuarioVendedor.o Juegos.o Venta.o EA.o Bugisoft.o Bandai.o JuegosSony.o JuegosNintendo.o JuegosMicrosoft.o Konami.o Sega.o SquareEnix.o ClaseAdmin.o -lboost_serialization -o Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens you most likely need to adapt your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. As you need to load shared library, and they are placed at some unusual place, you need to specifiy where they can be found when your program is executed.

I guess in your case they cannot be found in the folder `/usr/lib` but at some other place, then just add this folder to the mentionned environment variable, using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/new/path
```

And then start your program as usually.

The path `/some/new/path` is the path where the file `libboost_serialization.so` is located.

Comment: how can I add it into the makefile?

Comment: @AndreV Can you read the documentation on this site, especially the part about formatting code, and try again to show the contents of your Makefile.

Comment: That's nothing that belongs into your Makefile, but rather the environment must be set up properly. This can be done by always adding boost shared libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or by installing the libraries at some place such as `/usr/lib` or by setting the path in your `bashrc` (or similar), or whatever is appropriate in your case. The Makefile is important at compile time - it has no influence at runtime and where to actually find the shared library at runtime.

Comment: @overseas Actually the OP's issue happens during compilation and it can be fixed through the Makefile by adding a -L option to the g++ command. For the reason you list it may not be the best option, but the OP has said nothing about how he plans on running his program. Changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or the .bashrc file will apply to everything  that is compiled or ran in the environment, something he may want to avoid. For instance someone may have two different versions of boost installed for two different applications.

Comment: @Alain You would be right if your premise were right. But in this case you're totally wrong. The OP's issue does not happen during compilation as he clearly says in his post. The error message tells the same, otherwise the linker would tell about missing symbols if the `-l` part were missing or `cannot find -lboost_serialization` if the library cannot be found (here `-L` would help). But the OP's error message happens if at runtime the `.so`-file cannot be found, and certainly this is nothing you can (should) resolve using a Makefile.

Comment: @overseas how can I install the library at "/usr/lib"?

Comment: @overseas "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/new/path"  Thanks, this worked, I just didn't write the path correctly. Now, if I want to run this program in another computer, would I have to include the library in my program folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to run some script and add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH didn't work... so I simply copied the ".so" file to /usr/lib and it worked perfectly.